# Is there any difference in terms of meaning in these two sentences

Tags: meaning

Is there a difference in meaning between these two sentences

- When I'm doing compilations, I listen to soul music
- When I'm listening to soul music, I do compilation

---

Answer (score 1):

The meaning is the same, but the implication is different.

The first sentence implies that soul music somehow helps the process of you creating these compilations. After hearing that, I'd be tempted to ask something along the lines of "Does it help you focus?"

The second sentence implies that when you put on soul music, it spurs you to do compilations. This doesn't sound very natural to me, as it sounds like putting the cart before the horse. People usually put music on to help with a task, not put music on then be inspired to do a task. If you wanted to phrase it this way, a more natural sounding conversation would be along the lines of:

"I listen to soul music a lot. I find it helps me when I'm making my compilations"